# Purple Sprouting Broccoli recovery from bird attack

Tags: pest-damage, broccoli, birds

OK, I planted out my Broccoli earlier this year without realising that the birds *love* to snack on the leaves. They skeletonized the leaves, leaving only the veins on some of the larger leaves.

I've since put a rudimentary cloche over them which allowed some new growth to appear, though not much. Will they be able to recover, or is there something I can do to promote their return to health?

I have managed to crop a few small florets (no more than a good handful), and they tasted amazing, so I'm quite keen to get at least another decent harvest off of them.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the white butterfly around? I'd check carefully for eggs as they can hatch under your cloche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skeletonized leaves are more likely to be caused by slugs and snails or other pests rather than birds - birds tend to go for the florets or flowering heads rather than leaves.

Cropping from sprouting broccoli is usually over a 4-6 week period, so it may be their time is up, but you could try giving them liquid fertiliser to see if that gives them a boost. More information on general growing of broccoli in the link below, including a timetable for sowing and cropping. It's not quite yet too late to grow more if you want to

https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/grow-your-own/vegetables/broccoli